# How to serve views of AngularJS application using Spring boot?

Tags: angularjs, spring

I want to serve AngularJS application using spring boot (using embedded tomcat server). When I am serving the application by requesting index.html every thing is working fine. , but I want to directly serve the required view along with index.html.

For example,

If I have multiple views like `view1.html, view2.html(div elements)` and one of these views can be included in index.html. I want to create mapping using controller in springboot app which can directly load `index.html` with `view1.html or view2.html` depending upon the url pattern..

```
(\pattern1 -- will load the index.html along with view1. 

html and \pattern2 -- will load the index.html along with view2).
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of Angular router such as ui-router?

Comment: yes... but I to want serve directly a particular view as part of index.html depending on url pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could read your url from Angular with something like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/view1/:param1/:param2', {
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',    
    controller: 'MyCtrl1'
});
```

So depending on your url, template is changed at the time you access the view.
Of course you can manage it trough "states" via $stateProvider.